# Format BigDecimal or Number without Decimal Separator

Tags: java, format, bigdecimal

Hi i want to print a number with decimal values but without using decimal separator.

Ex: i have this 275.1234 but i want this 027512 (4 Digit 2 Decimal, all without separator)

i tried two approaches:

```
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0000.00");  
    DecimalFormatSymbols custom=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    custom.setDecimalSeparator('\u0000');
    format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);
    System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("275.1234")));
```

This print me: 0275 12 (i knew i can remove the space)

Second Approach:

```
    String[] value = new BigDecimal("275.1234").toString().split("\\.");
    System.out.println(value[0] + value[1].substring(0,2));
```

This print me: 27512 (Bad I need That The First 4 digits are filled with 0 if the number in question does not have integer 4 digits)

```
Ex: 1,1234 ==> 000112
Ex: 10,5678 ==> 001056
Ex: 100,7877 ==> 010078
```

Basically i want more elegant solution to this problem, any ideas?

Thanks
Ignacio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about multiplying by 100.

```
String text = String.format("%06.0f", Double.parseDouble("275.1234")*100);
```

or

```
String text = String.format("%06.0f", 275.1234 * 100);
```

or

```
String text = String.format("%06.0f", BigDecimal.valueOf(275.1234).doubleValue() * 100);
```

sets `text` to

```
027512
```

If you want to truncate rather than round you can do

```
String text = String.format("%06d", (long) (1234.5678 * 100));
```

prints

```
123456
```

Comment: @IgnacioAyuste I have fixed it now. It needs `"%06.0f"`

Comment: Now is working ok.
with BigDecimal too
String text = String.format("%06.0f", new BigDecimal("275.1234").multiply(new BigDecimal(100)));

Comment: I think this is bad solution because i lose the exact decimal, see this for ex
String.format("%06.0f", new BigDecimal("1234.5678").multiply(new BigDecimal(100))) this give me 123457 when the correct one is 123456

Comment: @IgnacioAyuste Not sure why you want to truncate rather than round, but you can do that too if you want.

Comment: String.format("%06d", (long) (1234.5678 * 100)); this worked ok, i want to truncate because is for an invoice and the client want to do in that way, thanks for the help.

Comment: How do the same but with BigDecimal?

Comment: @IgnacioAyuste You can call `bd.doubleValue()` and the value as a `double` as above. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
String value = "275.1234".replaceAll("\\.", "").substring(0, 5) ;
```

Comment: You want to be careful with this approach, the decimal separator can vary by locale, or be set explicitly (although this is uncommon). You can get the current one using `your_formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()`

Comment: This solution is bad because I need That The First 4 digits are filled with 0 if the number in question does not have 4 digits, in this case i need 027512 and you answer give me 27512.

Comment: @IgnacioAyuste i deliberately left it that way because you can always append a zero to it if you wish. For example "0" + "275.1234".replaceAll("\\.", "").substring(0, 5) or doing String.format("%0d", "275.1234".replaceAll("\\.", "").substring(0, 5)). My solution was just to show a relatively easy of way to remove dots(.) in decimal numbers.